# unknown directive "ssl_stapling"

Tags: ssl, nginx

I want SSL certificate on my website using nginx, but I did not get. At first I thought that the module is not installed --with-http_ssl_module, but after I gathered nginx with this module.

```
nginx version: nginx/1.2.1
built by gcc 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --with-debug --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-ipv6 --with-sha1=/usr/include/openssl --with-md5=/usr/include/openssl --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-http_ssl_module
```

nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.ru;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_certificate /www/nginx.conf/ssl/example.ru.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /www/nginx.conf/ssl/example.ru.key;
    ssl_ciphers 'HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!kEDH';
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /www/nginx.conf/ssl/ca-certs.pem;
}
```

sudo service nginx start

```
Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "ssl_stapling" in /www/nginx.conf/server.conf:26
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://nginx.org/r/ssl_stapling

> This directive appeared in version 1.3.7.

Read the docs, please.